# Why do my development websites in /var/www not load?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, virtualbox, development-environment

I configured an apache2 server on a virtualbox with ubuntu. This always worked but since yesterday my websites suddenly won't load annymore. I think it has something to do with our new network router but I'm not sure since it worked the first weeks. I have configured these things :

## 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName hello.int
        ServerAdmin email@hotmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/hello.int/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

## /etc/apache2/apache.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## hosts file in windows

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.2.15 hello.int
```

## shared map settings and network settings virtual box

[image]
[image]

## what I see when I surf to **localhost:8080**

[image]

## when I surf to hello.int (in windows host sytem)

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

## when I surf to 127.0.0.1 (in windows host system)

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

## when I ping to 127.0.0.1 (in windows host system)

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect from another computer on LAN to that VM?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, I ask you do you open the browser on that virtual machine system, or you open browser on your host system, when trying to access 127.0.0.1

Comment: I open the browser on my windows (host system) , when i open it on my vritual machine in ubuntu it gives me the same index list as i get when i type localhost:8080

Comment: So i get the  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on my windows host system

Comment: No it is the same computer where i run the Virtual machine on

Comment: Well is your server at virtual machine or is it in windows

Comment: My server is runned in virtual box on Ubuntu , but i work on my projects on the same computer out of the virtual box (in windows) in a shared folder. The thing i did before i started coding was just starting the Virtual box and i could access all my websites from the hosts file in windows , but suddenly they won't load annymore

Comment: Restart Firefox after you edit `/etc/hosts` and purge all caches (`Ctrl+Shift+Del`)